# High CPU usage when starting process with systemd

Tags: systemctl

I have this `service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/workingdir
ExecStart=/path/to/myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start `myservice` from the command line, it starts and deamonizes. When I start it with `-d` (for debug), it doesn't deamonize, but stops when hitting Enter.

However, when I put it as `myservice` in the `service` file, it doesn't start at all:

```
[root@localhost bin]# systemctl status myservice.service 
● myservice.service - MyService
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2023-08-22 09:20:21 CEST; 4min 1s ago
  Process: 1790032 ExecStart=/path/to/myservice (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1790032 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 22 09:20:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MyService
Aug 22 09:20:21 localhost.localdomain myservice[1790033]: myservice started with:
Aug 22 09:20:21 localhost.localdomain myservice[1790033]: current working dir: /path/to/workingdir
Aug 22 09:20:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: myservice.service: Succeeded.
```

And when starting it with `-d`, it starts, but raises up to 90% CPU usage.

How should I config a `service` file for a program that daemonizes by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does start, but from systemd's perspective it also immediately stops. The default `Type=simple` tells systemd to expect that the initial PID would also be the main PID; as soon as that process exits, the service "stops".

Use `Type=forking` for a service which daemonizes. Systemd will then wait for the initial process to exit, and will track the child as the main PID. (Usually it will guess the main PID automatically, but in some rare cases you might need to have the service write out a pidfile and specify that in systemd.)

It would be better if the service had "debug" and "don't daemonize" as two separate options. (And it would be even better if the service automatically recognized systemd's Type=notify protocol...)

Comment: Any thoughts on how the CPU usage can go through the roof when the `-d` option is given? When running with that option on the command line, all is well.

Comment: Does the same happen if you start it on the command line *and press Ctrl-D* instead of Enter? Or, if you start it with input redirected from `</dev/null`?

Comment: You said that the service in debug mode exits when you hit `Enter` on stdin, which implies it calls something like `read(stdin)` and sits there waiting for the call to return some input, looping until it gathers a whole line. But when started via systemd, the service has /dev/null attached to its stdin, so the read() call will _immediately_ return with a 0-byte result (the usual way to indicate "end of file"). And instead of checking for that condition and breaking out of the loop, your program keeps spinning in an infinite loop calling read() over and over (which you might see in `strace`).

Comment: yes, when I push Ctrl-D, I get the same high CPU usage. It uses `getchar` to wait for `\n`. Thanks a lot.